# Serve git-lfs files from express' public folder

Tags: express, heroku, amazon-s3, git-lfs

I'm using node.js (express) on Heroku, where the [slug size is limited to 300MB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#slug-size).

In order to keep my slug small, I'd like to use git-lfs to track my express' `public` folder.

In that way all my assets (images, videos...) are uploaded to a lfs-store (say AWS S3) and git-lfs leaves [a pointer file](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md#the-pointer) (with probably the S3 URL in it?).

**I'd like express redirects to the remote S3 file when serving files from the public folder.**

My problem is I don't kwon how to retrieve the URL from the pointer file's content...

```js
app.use('/public/:pointerfile', function (req, res, next) {
  var file = req.params.pointerfile;
  fs.readFile('public/'+file, function (er, data) {
    if (er) return next(er);

    var url = retrieveUrl(data); // <-- HELP ME HERE with the retrieveUrl function

    res.redirect(url);
  });
});
```

Don't you think it will not be too expensive to make express read and parse potentially all the `public/*` files. Maybe I could cache the URL once parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally made a middleware for this: **[express-lfs](https://github.com/goodenough/express-lfs)** with a demo here: https://expresslfs.herokuapp.com

There you can download a 400Mo file as a proof.

See usage here: https://github.com/goodenough/express-lfs#usage

PS: Thanks to @fundeldman for good advices in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902385/serve-git-lfs-files-from-express-public-folder#37044083) ;)

Answer (score 10):

Actually the `pointer` file doesn't contain any url information in it (as can be seen in the link you provided, or [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-large-file-storage/)) - it just keeps the `oid`(Object ID) for the blob which is just its `sha256`.

You can however achieve what you're looking for using the `oid` and the lfs [api](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/api) that allows you to download specific `oid`s using the [batch request](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/http-v1-batch-request-schema.json).

You can tell what is the endpoint that's used to store your blobs from `.git/config` which can accept non-default `lfsurl` tags such as:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = https://...
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   lfsurl = "https://..."
```

or a separate

```
[lfs]
   url = "https://..."
```

If there's no `lfsurl` tag then you're using GitHub's endpoint (which may in turn redirect to S3):

```
Git remote: https://git-server.com/user/repo.git
Git LFS endpoint: https://git-server.com/user/repo.git/info/lfs

Git remote: git@git-server.com:user/repo.git
Git LFS endpoint: https://git-server.com/user/repo.git/info/lfs
```

But you should work against it and not S3 directly, as GitHub's redirect response will probably contain some authentication information as well.

Check the [batch response](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/http-v1-batch-response-schema.json) doc to see the response structure - you will basically need to parse the relevant parts and make your own call to retrieve the blobs (which is what `git lfs` would've done in your stead during checkout).

A typical response (taken from the doc I referenced) would look something like:

```
{
   "_links": {
     "download": {
       "href": "https://storage-server.com/OID",
       "header": {
         "Authorization": "Basic ...",
       }
     }
  }
}
```

So you would `GET` `https://storage-server.com/OID` with whatever `headers` was returned from the batch response - the last step will be to rename the blob that was returned (it's name will typically be just the `oid` as git lfs uses checksum based storage) - the pointer file has the original resource's name so just rename the blob to that.

Comment: thx @fundeldman, could you develop a bit more about the request to make to grab the ressource URL with the batch API (without github and authorization)? many thanks